# How to represent an instance of a class as a string inside a class function in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Not sure if instance is the right word, but I hope you will understand what I'm trying to do.
Here is an example of what I would like the Code to do:

```
class name:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "hello "
    def say_hello(self):
        print(self.a + str(self))

Jorge = name()
Bruno = name()
Jorge.say_hello()
Bruno.say_hello()
```

The output will be this

```
hello <__main__.name object at 0x000002C80D4CEEB0>
hello <__main__.name object at 0x000002C80C9FC250>
```

But I want it to be like this

```
hello Jorge
hello Bruno
```

I thought that "self" corresponds with "Jorge" in that regard since I can use "print(Jorge.a)" to print "hello " outside the class function, and "print(self.a)" inside the class function.
Is there a way to do that?

Thank you for your time, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class name:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hello(self):
        print("hello " + self.__repr__())

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return "this is my name: {}".format(self.name)


Jorge = name("Jorge")
Bruno = name("Bruno")
Jorge.say_hello()
Bruno.say_hello()
print(Jorge)
```

Comment: It does the job but its not what I meant... If I write ```Jorge = name("Bruno"); Jorge.say_hello()``` it will print me "hello Bruno". I still want it to print "hello Jorge"

Comment: Generally you don't use instance name of the class within the class, convention is getting the name as a class variable.

Comment: There are some ways to achive that functionality but in some cases instances has no unique names for example you could have a list of nameless class instances, so even tho there is a workaround it will be fragile. If you really want to do this use this in a function ```return [k for k,v in globals().items() if v is self]```